# SQL-Query for Moodle

Tags: php, sql, moodle

I would like to use an SQL query in Moodle to find out in which courses a student with user ID 100 is enrolled and then output these courses as a website.

What I would need is the query command to find out which courses it is enrolled in.

Can you help me?

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

For getting the list of courses a User with user ID 100 is enrolled:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(u.firstname, " " ,u.lastname) AS Student, course.fullname AS Course
FROM mdl_course AS course 
JOIN mdl_enrol AS en ON en.courseid = course.id
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments AS ue ON ue.enrolid = en.id
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON ue.userid = u.id
WHERE u.id = 100
```

You can use `roleid` for restricting it to any role.

Have you seen https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports? You will get some amazing reporting queries.

Comment: Many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, thank you !!!!!!!